# Magento PopUpAjaxCart Does Not Show the Options For Configurable Products

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, ajax

[image: The image I am referring to]

Attached is the picture of what my problem is. I have configurable products that i want the end user to select options from. While the popup with the id popUpAjaxCart appears, but there are no options available to select.

Things i have tried: 1. Fixing the configurable swatches 2. Trying to edit the phtml file 3. Trying to edit the js file at public_html/theme/js/magiccart/ajaxcart.js

Note: I have a theme so magiccart is the name of the theme folder.

Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->getChildHtml('product_options_wrapper');
```

For show configurable options.
If your theme extends base theme.